# Mosaic Image Gallery in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

I want to make a mosaic gallery with pure CSS, but I can't think of the "logic-side", I need a practical example.

Can you guide me?

I have seen [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054080/css-image-gallery-float-bug), but I don't understand how to achieve it.

Here is an example of what I need: http://tmv.proto.jp/

I would like a non-jQuery solution.

Comment: @Jcubed Fluid. Exactly like this http://losec0ntrol.tumblr.com/

Comment: You can see a live example on make a mosaic of image in HTML/CSS : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22412842/1811992

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make some divs to serve as columns. Then you use css to give them all a width (percent for fluid, px for fixed) and float them left.
Second, give all your images a width of 100% in css and distribute them among the columns.

Example (untested):

HTML:

```
<div class='col'>
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
</div>

<div class='col'>
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Jcubed! Thank you for your entry. It works! But, if possible, you can tell me the logic to apply this on a foreach(php)? If I have the correctly logic, I can make the code.

Comment: foreach(images as i=>image){
        divs[i%Number_Divs][]=image;
    }

Then echo out the divs using another foreach.

Hope that helps.