# Mosaic of images HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid-layout, aspect-ratio

I want to make an image layout with **portrait images** inside a `div` with a fixed aspect ratio of `3:2`. The size of images is `327x491px`.

The main issue is unwanted spaces between images. How do I **align images as a mosaic** using only *HTML/CSS*?

*HTML :*

```
<div id="pictures1" class="_pictures1 grid">
    <div class="_pictures1-01"><div style="width:125px;height: 188px; background: red;"><img src="" width="125" height="188" alt="" /></div></div>
    <div class="_pictures1-02"><div style="width:192px;height: 288px;background: green;"><img src="" width="192" height="288" alt="" /></div></div>
     ... SO ON ...
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
._pictures1 {
    width: 935px; height: 490px;
    margin: -26px 0 0 59px;
    float: left;
    top: 20%; left: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px gray solid;
}
._pictures1 div {position: absolute;}
._pictures1-01 {top: 0px; left: 35px;}
._pictures1-02 {top: 200px; left: 0px;}
/* ... SO ON ... */
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jd4z4/1/)

Comment: I think the easiest way to do it, is to use a css grid framework.

Comment: Try setting width and heights on the divs containing the images, also add `position: relative` on those divs; for `img` add `max-width:100%; max-height:100%`

Comment: How will you generate this markup? Server side? js, or just manually for an specific page?

Comment: its static markup in html now

Comment: @Aleks how to remove that spaces between div then?

Comment: @Sumit I do not understand what you want to achieve? You wrote the heights of the images are 491px. In your posted code you have 488px, but 188px + 288px = 476px! So you probably should get your math fixed first. Furthermore your code looks a bit like "Divitis" and overly complicated. When I understand what is your goal I will post an alternative solution.

Comment: @Netsurfer images pixels size is fixed 491 and 327 and vice versa ie. have ratio 3/2 and 2/3 vice versa so 325/488 = 2/3

Comment: With your layout it's not possible. Only if parts of the images are cut can it be achieved. It's because the smaller images are less wide if you maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: @HerrSerker Good point! I still do not understand what the OP wants to achieve!? And I still have the impression that there is an error in thinking ...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To make a proper answer, I am first going to clarify the requirements :

1. images all have the same aspect ratio : 3/2
2. images shouldn't be cropped
3. no space between images
4. make a mosaic of images

You can have thousands of possibilities to display your images. I am going to make a simple layout that should show you the way to build your own.

Here is a **[FANCY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/zMMH5/334/)** of what you can achieve and here is what it looks like :

[image: Mosaic of images in html/css - example layout]

Code :

```css
body, html {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrap {
    width:984px;
    height:492px;
}
.big_col, .medium_col, .small_col{
    height:492px;
    float:left;
}
img {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    float:left;
}
.big_col {
    width:328px;
}
.medium_col{
    width:164px;
}
.small_col{
    width:82px;
}
.big_img img {
    width:328px;
    height:492px
}
.medium_img img {
    width:164px;
    height:246px;
}
.small_img img {
    width:82px;
    height:123px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="big_col">
        <div class="small_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/241/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/147/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/258/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/328/492" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="medium_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/356/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/254/328/492" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="small_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/156/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/175/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/132/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/197/328/492" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="big_col">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/328/492" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="small_col small_img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/210/328/492" alt="" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/152/328/492" alt="" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/142/328/492" alt="" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/189/328/492" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="medium_col medium_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/254/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/111/328/492" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="small_col small_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/198/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/201/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/286/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/145/328/492" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### First step : think, calculate and think again

**First :** To make it simple let's say your images can have 3 sizes (I changed the image size by 1 px to make calculations easier) :

1. big : `328*492px`
2. medium, 1/2 of big : `164*246px`
3. small, 1/4 of big : `82*123px`

**Second :** As your images are all portraits and your container has the same height as the big image, you will have to work with 492px heigh columns that can have 3 widths :

1. big : `328px` wide, they can display all size images
2. medium : `328/2 = 164px` wide, they can display medium and small images
3. small : `327/4 = 82px` wide, they can only display small images

**Third :** How many columns and what image sizes? This is up to you, you will have to make a choice according to the total width of your container and the number of images you want to display.

But in your fiddle, the container (`._pictures1`) has a `935px` width which will be impossible to achieve with the column widths chosen just before.

```
935/82 = 11.4024...
```

The closest you can get is `82*12 = 984px` wide container.

You will either have to change the width of the container either change the sizes of images and columns to fit your initial width.

---

**Or** (spoiler) you can work with percentages, this can be an alternative especialy if you need your layout to be responsive but this can become complicated and I am trying to make things simple.

As I am sure you are curious and want to check it out, here is an example layout in a

## [Responsive mosaic of image fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/zMMH5/336/embedded/result/)

Code snippet :

```css
body, html {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrap {
    width:100%;
}
.big_col, .medium_col, .small_col{
    float:left;
}
img {
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    float:left;
}
.big_col {
    width:25%;
}
.medium_col{
    width:12.5%;
}
.small_col{
    width:6.25%;
}

.small_col img{
    width:100%;
}
.medium_col>img {
    width:100%;
}
.medium_col .small_img img {
    width:50%;
}
.big_col .small_img img {
    width:25%;
}
.big_col .medium_img img {
    width:50%;
}
.big_col img {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="big_col">
        <div class="small_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/241/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/147/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/258/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/328/492" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="medium_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/356/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/254/328/492" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="small_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/156/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/175/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/132/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/197/328/492" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="big_col">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/328/492" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="small_col small_img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/210/328/492" alt="" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/152/328/492" alt="" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/142/328/492" alt="" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/189/328/492" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="medium_col medium_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/254/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/111/328/492" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="small_col small_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/198/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/201/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/145/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/198/328/492" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### Next step : design the layout

Use a pen, photoshop, or any other tool that suits you, if you are realy good you can even use your brain to mentaly represent the layout you want.

I designed the image you can see at the bigininng of the answer.

As I said before there are many layout posibilities (number of columns and sizes of images in those columns) so for the example I chose 2 big columns 1 medium and 2 small ones

```
328*2+164+82*2 = 984px ( = width of container so it can fit!)
```

---

### Last step : start coding!

You can see the result in this

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/zMMH5/338/)

This layout is based on [floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) so we need to define in the width, height of container, columns, images so they can all fit next to each other nicely (as we have already thought about that with calculation and design, it's easy).

```css
body, html {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrap {
    width:984px;
    height:492px;
}
.big_col, .medium_col, .small_col{
    height:492px;
    float:left;
}
img {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    float:left;
}
.big_col {
    width:328px;
}
.medium_col{
    width:164px;
}
.small_col{
    width:82px;
}
.big_img img {
    width:328px;
    height:492px
}
.medium_img img {
    width:164px;
    height:246px;
}
.small_img img {
    width:82px;
    height:123px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="big_col">
        <div class="small_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/241/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/147/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/258/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/328/492" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="medium_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/356/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/254/328/492" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="small_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/156/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/175/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/132/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/197/328/492" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="big_col">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/328/492" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="small_col small_img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/210/328/492" alt="" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/152/328/492" alt="" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/142/328/492" alt="" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/189/328/492" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="medium_col medium_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/254/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/111/328/492" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="small_col small_img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/198/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/201/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/145/328/492" alt="" />
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/198/328/492" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Congrats! This is the first real answer to what the OP presumably wants to achieve! Maybe it's worth to think about replacing the 'float' by `display: table[-cell]` or `display: inline-block`, but anyway a +1 from my side!

Comment: @Netsurfer thanks for your comment :). I thought about those alternative solutions but I think floats suit the OP's situation better because `display:inline-block;` whould create whitespace to deal whith and `display:table-cell;` isn't as crossbrower as floats.

Comment: Sadly the lorempixum.com site is defunct, breaking these fiddles. Anyone volunteer to fix?

Comment: @JeffAxelrod I changed the placeholder image provider and added code snippets ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you set one dimension or the other, but not both, the images should resize fluidly. Try setting just the width to a percentage unit.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to remove space between images, just remove set to '0' `padding` and `margin`.

Then to achive what you want, you can use or combine those strategies:

1) Assign a fixed size in pixel to one of the sizes: other one will scale automatically.

2) You can calculate the size you need via javascript and assign the value dinamically.
For example with jQuery framework:

```
$(img).each(function(){
 var h = this.height();
 var w = this.width();


 if (w => h){
  this.attr('width', w*0.66);
}
else {
  this.attr('height',h*.066);
}
});
```

3) You can use css background-image for divs and `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain` as you need, statically or dinamically ([w3c docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning doesn't seem to be the best choice if you want to dynamically keep the same positions and ratio.

**Native HTML flow is usually the way to go.** 
Absolute positioning is like vitamin tablets. You use it when you need it, but it's not your main food. ;)

What I would do is :

> 1. simply position the container as wanted (centered for example) and size its width with percentage of the window/section it's in.
> 2. Then you put your ._pictures1-xx divs inside it, and size the pics' width using percentage of the container. Height will keep ratio automatically (*)
> 3. I would then make the ._pictures1-xx divs display "inline-block" and float "left". Then a little div with clear"both" after the last pic and close the container.

(*) reminder : the width or height default value is "auto", meaning any size that keeps the image ratio when the other is a px/% value.
The horizontal margins natively become dynamic when your pics' height is defined, in order to keep your pics' ratios. If you define width and leave height auto, then the height is dynamic in order to keep the pics' ratio, and margins don't change.

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give simple solution.

You can simply wrap `img` tag with DIV. And you should apply CSS to this wrapped DIV.

#### Example Code

Instead of this

```
<img src='some_image.jpg'>
```

Use below kind of structure

```
<div class="img_wrapper">
     <img src='some_image.jpg'>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
//  suggestion: target IMG with parent class / ID
.img_wrapper img{
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
}
```

All images inside class `.img_wrapper` would have proper aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your image with a div. set width and height for the div according to ratio. Give only height for image. If you want the image to take only space they need use display:inline also

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

Styling

```
body{
    background: black;
    width:80%;
    margin:5em auto;
    display:block;
}
.wrapper{
    background:#FFF;
    float:left;
}   

.container{
    height:476px;
    width:192px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.small{
    height:188px;
    width:125px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#333;
}
.medium{
    background:#666;
    width:192px;
    height:288px;
}
.large{
    height:476px;
    width:200px;
    background:#999;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

This is HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="small">
            <div class="small_inner">
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="medium">
            <div class="medium_inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large">
        <div class="large_inner">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="medium">
            <div class="medium_inner">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="small">
            <div class="small_inner">
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="large">
        <div class="large_inner">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="small">
            <div class="small_inner">
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="medium">

            <div class="medium_inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
 height: auto;
 width: 50%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

aspectRatioResizeImg 
This is a jQuery plugin that allows resizing of an image preserving its aspect ratio, fitting a container. Optionally the container can be resized to match the image aspect ratio.
https://github.com/stereoactivo/jquery.resize-image-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0):

In my experience: if you only set the dimension of **either** height or the width (**not both**) the image will scale accordingly.