# How do I put images side to side no matter what height/width

Tags: css

I've been trying to find an explanation on Google but I don't really know where to start. I'm basically trying to have this effect: [link](http://www.danielsenphoto.com/portfolio.html) Eventhough they have different heights and widths, they still are side to side with no white space between them. Oh and I'm using Drupal so I don't know if I only need css for this.

Comment: you should look at this. http://masonry.desandro.com/ and as you are using Drupal . might be helpful for you. https://www.drupal.org/project/masonry

Comment: masonry might be the best bet for you but if you want to hard code it, you can take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221333/make-a-mosaic-of-images-in-html-css/22412842#22412842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this effect, you should try this javascript plugin "masonry" which works great:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Here a demo:
http://erikjohanssonphoto.com/work/imagecats/personal/

Comment: while I was writing I think Kheema Pandey has written a similar answer/comment, perhaps more adapted to drupal