# Mosaic Gallery effect with jQuery or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to achieve this `Mosaic`(?) effect but I'm unsure where to begin. Is there a plugin I can use?

Here is my current code:
https://jsfiddle.net/z3bhh9gj/

```
<section id="intro">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x620">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x300">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x620">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Here is what the final outcome should look like: 
[image]

Should I be looking at Masonry or Isotope for this?

Appreciate any help :-)

Comment: This can be helpfull: [Mosaic of images HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221333/mosaic-of-images-html-css)

Comment: You're asking for specific tools, for which Stack Overflow isn't the best place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nice plugin for that

1. [GridALicious](http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/)
2. [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: GridALicious looks the ticket - thank you, Goran!

Answer (score -1):

Masonry is a layout and Isotope is a plugin that provides masonry layout and filtering and more. There is a masonry plugin:

[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html)

Isotope uses this library.

[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html)