# Loop an array based on condition in php

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

I need help with forming an HTML div based on array loop.

My array looks like below

```
$myarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
```

PHP file looks like

```
<?php
foreach ($myarray as $arr) {
    //I dont know how to add condition here
    echo "<div class='custom_style'>" . $arr ."</div>";
}
```

This is how my output should come
[image]

Let me explain clearly. Initially, I want first 2 array key would be big size then next 4 will be a small size. Again next 2 will be big and next 4 will be small..so on..I want to loop in this way till my array ends.

Please ignore CSS part.i will write by own

Comment: search about "html mosaic layout" , this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221333/mosaic-of-images-html-css

Comment: put the code of custom_style css

Comment: @Mehul Jariwala I just want the logic...i will write custom style later based on logic

Comment: wait sir i create logic

Comment: @aidin I need to form div dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can avoid using "counters" if you just declare the key variable in your foreach loop.
- You can avoid multiple conditionals if you leverage the modulus operator (`%`).  It divides the first number by the second and outputs the remainder.
- The indices provided by the foreach loop will start from `0`, so the indices that you wish to display as big blocks will include: `0`,`1`,`6`,`7`,`12`,and `13`.  When `$i%6` is applied to these keys, the output will be `0` or `1`.
- Since the only thing that is changing in our echo statement is the class attribute, there is no need to repeat the full `<div>` line.  DRY programming practices dictates that you only modify the end of the class value.  To accomplish this, I have opted for an inline conditional.

This is the best/simplest way for you to accomplish your desired output.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a17624352d839ad4c14b43768b23126a117dd24c))

```
$myarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
foreach ($myarray as $i=>$v){
    echo "<div class=\"cust",($i%6<2?1:2),"\">$v</div>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<div class="cust1">1</div>
<div class="cust1">2</div>
<div class="cust2">3</div>
<div class="cust2">4</div>
<div class="cust2">5</div>
<div class="cust2">6</div>
<div class="cust1">7</div>
<div class="cust1">8</div>
<div class="cust2">9</div>
<div class="cust2">10</div>
<div class="cust2">11</div>
<div class="cust2">12</div>
<div class="cust1">13</div>
<div class="cust1">14</div>
<div class="cust2">15</div>
<div class="cust2">16</div>
<div class="cust2">17</div>
<div class="cust2">18</div>
```

---

Alternatively, if you aren't worried about satifying all browsers, you can use a pure css solution with `nth-child()` and `implode()`.

```
<style> 
div:nth-child(6n+1),div:nth-child(6n+2) {
    background: red;
}
</style>
<?php
$myarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
echo '<div>',implode('</div><div>',$myarray),'</div>';  // glue each value with a closing and opening div tag
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

i write logic for your dynamic boxes now you need to create your css.

```
<html>
<style>
#cust_1
{
    border: 1px solid red; 
    min-width:90px; 
    min-height:90px; 
    display: inline-block;
}

#cust_2
{
    border: 1px solid red; 
    min-width:40px; 
    min-height:40px; 
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<?php
$myarray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12);
$i = 1;

foreach ($myarray as $arr)
 {

     if($i <= 2){
        echo "<div id=cust_1>". $arr . "</div>";
        $i++;
     }
    else if($i==6){ 
            $i=1;
        echo "<div id=cust_2>". $arr . "</div>";
    }else{
        echo "<div id=cust_2>". $arr . "</div>";
        $i++;
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Not only did Exprator answer first, his answer doesn't make the mistake of declaring duplicate ids to the dom.